# Using CONCAT to perform partial searches, won't work

Tags: excel, concatenation, countif

I have a feeling this has a simple answer but I've been poking away at this for an hour without much progress so I figure either A) there is a simple limiting rule as to why this won't work, that I'm unfamiliar with or B) there is a formatting fix.

Below I have a basic data set to try and highlight the issue, in this case we could manage manually but when this gets more extensive it becomes impossible.

```
Program leader          
Alpha   2   3   
Bravo   3   5   
Charlie 1   2   
 Program ID number  Program leader/leaders  Core task/tasks
 123    Alpha    Training
 114    Charlie  Clearing
 309    Bravo, Charlie   Clearing
 2290   Bravo   Contact, Clearing
 192    Alpha, Bravo    Engagement
 103    Bravo   Mapping
 4039   Alpha   Contact
 1930   Bravo   Training
```

So below Program leader those are countif functions, the first is Countif with cell reference, the second is with text "*Alpha*" etc.

So I put together a CONCAT set to construct this based on cell reference

```
CONCAT(CHAR(34), "*", A2, "*", CHAR(34))
```

Which independently renders "*Alpha*" when setup on it's own in a cell, however when I put that in as the Criteria element within parentheses as such

```
  =COUNTIF(C$6:C$13, CONCAT(CHAR(34), "*", A2, "*", CHAR(34)))
```

The value returned is 0 instead of 3 for Alpha, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the double quotes in the string:

```
=COUNTIF(C$6:C$13, CONCAT("*", A2, "*"))
```

Comment: Dangit, that was so simple I can't believe I didn't figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have newer version of excel but this should work too with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
 =SUM(IF(C$6:C$13=CONCAT( "*", A2, "*"),1))
```

Comment: I don't believe that the literal `"` wrappers are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the concat operator is cleaner and more efficient (marginally) than the CONCAT function.

```
=COUNTIF(C$6:C$13, "*"&A2&"*")
```